# Unknown access type record

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to add a Weather object to the database using jakarta and jparepository. The following error occurs: Unknown access type record. Initially, there was javax instead of jakarta, but there was an error that the object was unmanaged. I changed to jakarta and a new error appeared. When replacing JpaRepository with Crudrepository, nothing changes either.

```
package com.example.weather;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.weather.repository")
public class WeatherApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.weather.repository;

import com.example.weather.model.Weather;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface WeatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather, Long> {

}
```

```
package com.example.weather.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;



import java.io.Serializable;
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "weather")
public class Weather implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "temp")
    @JsonProperty("temp")
    private int temp;
    @Column(name = "wind_speed")
    @JsonProperty("wind_speed")
    private double wind_speed;
    @Column(name = "wind_degrees")
    @JsonProperty("wind_degrees")
    private double wind_degrees;
    @Column(name = "humidity")
    @JsonProperty("humidity")
    private int humidity;
    @Column(name = "sunset")
    @JsonProperty("sunset")
    private int sunset;
    @Column(name = "min_temp")
    @JsonProperty("min_temp")
    private int min_temp;
    @Column(name = "cloud_pct")
    @JsonProperty("cloud_pct")
    private int cloud_pct;
    @Column(name = "feels_like")
    @JsonProperty("feels_like")
    private int feels_like;
    @Column(name = "sunrise")
    @JsonProperty("sunrise")
    private int sunrise;
    @Column(name = "max_temp")
    @JsonProperty("max_temp")
    private int max_temp;

    public void Print(){
        System.out.println(String.format("id = %s\ncity = %s\ntemp = %s\nwind_speed = %s\nwind_degrees = %s\n" +
                "humidity = %s\nsunset = %s\nmin_temp = %s\ncloud_pct = %s\nfeels_like = %s\nsunrise = %s\nmax_temp = %s",
                id, city, temp, wind_speed, wind_degrees, humidity, sunset, min_temp, cloud_pct, feels_like, sunrise, max_temp));
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.weather.controller;

import com.example.weather.jms.WeatherListener;
import com.example.weather.jms.WeatherProducer;
import com.example.weather.model.Weather;
import com.example.weather.repository.WeatherRepository;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/weather")
@Transactional
public class WeatherController {

    private final WeatherProducer weatherProducer;
    private final WeatherListener weatherListener;
    private final WeatherRepository weatherRepository;

    @Autowired
    public WeatherController(WeatherProducer weatherProducer, WeatherListener weatherListener, WeatherRepository weatherRepository) {
        this.weatherProducer = weatherProducer;
        this.weatherListener = weatherListener;
        this.weatherRepository = weatherRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("{city}")
    public int getWeather(@PathVariable String city) throws Exception{
        URL url = new URL("https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/weather?city=" + city);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("X-Api-Key", "aCQf5mYIfKNIhy2etdORbQ==4lC2SUpMjyg9CTpq");
        InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(responseStream);
        Weather weather = mapper.readValue(root.toString(), Weather.class);
        weather.setCity(city);

        //weatherProducer.sendWeather(weather);
        weatherRepository.save(weather);

        int currentTemperature = weather.getTemp();

        return currentTemperature;
    }
}
```

Error code:

```
2023-06-12T19:16:36.570+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.example.weather.WeatherApplication   : Starting WeatherApplication using Java 20.0.1 with PID 21364 (C:\Users\Professional\IdeaProjects\weather\target\classes started by Professional in C:\Users\Professional\IdeaProjects\weather)
2023-06-12T19:16:36.572+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.example.weather.WeatherApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-06-12T19:16:37.174+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-06-12T19:16:37.236+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 54 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-06-12T19:16:37.733+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-06-12T19:16:37.743+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-06-12T19:16:37.743+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-06-12T19:16:37.835+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-06-12T19:16:37.835+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1207 ms
2023-06-12T19:16:37.987+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-06-12T19:16:38.044+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.2.Final
2023-06-12T19:16:38.046+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-06-12T19:16:38.095+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-06-12T19:16:38.626+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-06-12T19:16:38.773+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-06-12T19:16:38.789+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-06-12T19:16:38.977+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@31e7afde
2023-06-12T19:16:38.978+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-06-12T19:16:39.014+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.dialect                : HHH035001: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect, version: 10.0
2023-06-12T19:16:39.015+03:00  WARN 21364 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: PostgreSQL10Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect instead
2023-06-12T19:16:39.123+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-06-12T19:16:39.353+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-06-12T19:16:39.359+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-12T19:16:39.546+03:00  WARN 21364 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherController' defined in file [C:\Users\Professional\IdeaProjects\weather\target\classes\com\example\weather\controller\WeatherController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository' defined in com.example.weather.repository.WeatherRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.weather.model.Weather
2023-06-12T19:16:39.547+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-12T19:16:39.548+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-06-12T19:16:39.604+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-06-12T19:16:39.606+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-12T19:16:39.619+03:00  INFO 21364 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-12T19:16:39.636+03:00 ERROR 21364 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherController' defined in file [C:\Users\Professional\IdeaProjects\weather\target\classes\com\example\weather\controller\WeatherController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository' defined in com.example.weather.repository.WeatherRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.weather.model.Weather
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.example.weather.WeatherApplication.main(WeatherApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'weatherRepository' defined in com.example.weather.repository.WeatherRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Not a managed type: class com.example.weather.model.Weather
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.weather.model.Weather
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:80) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Looks as if you try to use the wrong Java version to compile code. How do you compile the code (just inside IDE, maven, gradle, ... ?) and which Java version is used? Please also add the used spring boot version.

Comment: inside IDE, java version is 18

Comment: I'm going to guess that part of your code is using `record`s and that your Spring version doesn't support them

Comment: Can you please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: I added the full stacktrace to the error code block

Comment: Try changing the basePackages argument to "com.example.weather"

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue caused have conflicting hibernate core version， after I remove the older one, and keep the 6.2.6.Final one. start successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following and it seems to work. Please note that I am using Spring Boot 3.1.3, reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#other-integrations-orm6

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm-orm6</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-lucene</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I tried to use hibernate-search-orm-mapper.
The problem is this particular dependency is not managed by springboot-starter-data-jpa. So data-jpa tried to use hibernate 6.2.2 jar while search-orm-mapper tried to use 5.1.2.

I had to check for which version both use same hibernate-core jar.. that sweet co-incidence for my case is spring version 2.6.6 and search-orm version 6.1.3-Final now both use hibernate-core 5.6.7

Similar way you have to find for your case.. use mvn dependency:tree to find duplicate dependencies with different versions, you will find your culprit there then check in maven central for both dependencies and see for which version compile dependencies matches..

Comment: can you check my spring boot question as well

Answer (score 0):

Editing pom.xml with the latest hibernate dependency solved this issue for me.

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```